# nextflow: data not being published to output dir after process is complete

Tags: groovy, workflow, nextflow

I've following nextflow code where haplotype from gatk is run. The code is run fine, it geenrates files in the `work` directory's sub-directory, however, they are not pushes/published to the output directory.

Below are the codes:

`haplotype.nf`

```
process haplotype {

        maxForks 3
        debug true
        errorStrategy 'retry'
    maxRetries 4
 label 'medium_mem'

publishDir path: "${params.outdir}/${sample_name}/haplotype/normal/", mode: 'copy', pattern: "_N*"

publishDir path: "${params.outdir}/${sample_name}/haplotype/tumor/", mode: 'copy', pattern: "_T*"

input:

        tuple val(sample_id_tumor),path(bqsrbam_tumor, stageAs: 'tumor_haplotype/*')
        tuple val(sample_id_normal),path(bqsrbam_normal, stageAs: 'normal_haplotype/*')

output:
        tuple val(sample_id_tumor), path("${sample_id_tumor}_raw.snps.indels.vcf.idx"), emit: haplotyper_tumor_idx
        tuple val(sample_id_tumor), path("${sample_id_tumor}_raw.snps.indels.vcf"), emit: haplotyper_tumor
        tuple val(sample_id_normal), path( "${sample_id_normal}_raw.snps.indels.vcf"), emit: haplotyper_normal
        tuple val(sample_id_normal), path( "${sample_id_normal}_raw.snps.indels.vcf.idx"), emit: haplotyper_normal_idx

script:

sample_name=sample_id_normal.split('_N')[0]

"""

/data1/software/gatk-4.3.0.0/gatk HaplotypeCaller -I ${bqsrbam_tumor} --intervals $params.bed_target --O "${sample_id_tumor}_raw.snps.indels.vcf" -R $params.hg38genome

/data1/software/gatk-4.3.0.0/gatk HaplotypeCaller -I ${bqsrbam_normal} --intervals $params.bed_target --O "${sample_id_normal}_raw.snps.indels.vcf" -R $params.hg38genome


"""

}

workflow.onComplete { 
        log.info ( workflow.success ? "Done haplotype caller!" : "Oops .. something went wrong in haplotype caller"  )
}
```

I can find it in the work dir.

```
find ./ -name "MM-0489_T_raw.snps.indels.vcf"
./work/0d/b7a720dcac3c4b4e7bc0a48a51ede5/MM-0489_T_raw.snps.indels.vcf
```

The `main.nf` has

```
include { FASTP} from './fastp_process.nf'

include { align_bwa_mem} from './bwamem_process_already_index.nf'
include { fixmate } from './fixmate_information.nf'
include { gatk_markduplicates} from './gatk_markduplicates_process.nf'
include {setupnmdtags} from './setupnmdtags_process.nf'
include { recalibrate_bam } from './recalibratebam_process.nf'
include { applybqsr } from './applybqsr_process.nf'
include { mutect2 } from './mutect2_process.nf'
include { manta } from './manta_process.nf'
include { lancet } from './lancet_process.nf'

include { collectmetrics } from './collectmetrics.nf'

include {haplotype } from './haplotypecaller.nf'
include { score_variants } from './scorevariants.nf'
include { filter_tranches } from './filter_tranches.nf'
```

The processes are complete with no errors.

Does the order of processes matter in the `main.nf` to publish output in the output dir?

Comment: Hummm... the name you are looking for in the `find` command (`MM-0489_T_raw.snps.indels.vcf`) does not match the pattern you have in the `publishDir` directive (`"_N*"` and `"_T*"`). Could that be the reason?

Comment: How come it doesn't match? `_T*` will capture `_T_` isn't it? How do I name files to capture regex as provided in output dir?

Comment: Yes, it will capture `_T_`. but not `whatever_T_`. And you don't have `_T_` in the find, you have more things. Unless it is making partial matches. I'm not an expert, so I'm just guessing. I assumed that partial matches were not considered because you used a star in the pattern, otherwise if partial matches were considered, the star won't be needed.
So, you specify only part of the pattern and no stars are needed, or you put stars in any place where you expect something, but your current code is a half baked solution.

Comment: can you please help me the code as it's half baked?

Comment: Again, I'm not an expert, I didn't tried the solution and I'm just guessing, but I'd say that in the case of partial matches considered, the patterns should be like `_N`, and in the case of partial matches not considered, the patterns should be like `*_N*`.
This is assuming a wildcard style of many shells and globbing engines. If these patterns are regular expressions, then the second case should be written as `.*_N.*`.

Comment: If that's not working then a workaround could be to be less stringent with the glob patterns and move tumor and normal vcfs into specific directories. 

So, `mkdir tumour_out; mkdir normal_out`, then in the `haplotypecaller` command use `--O ./tumor_out/"${sample_id_tumor}_raw.snps.indels.vcf` and the `output` declaration goes `path(./tumor_out/*.vcf)`. Not ideal, but a potential workaround until you figure out what's going on.