# nextflow - Module compilation error """ in the process script

Tags: groovy, pipeline, nextflow

I've below code in snp pile up nextflow script.

`snp_pileup.nf`

```
process snp_pileup {

conda '/data1/software/miniconda3/envs/datum'

        maxForks 3
        debug true
        errorStrategy 'retry'
    maxRetries 4
        label 'low_mem'
        publishDir path: "${params.outdir}/${sample_name}/snppileup/", mode: 'copy'

input:
        tuple val(sample_id_tumor),path(bqsrbam_tumor, stageAs: 'tumor_snppileup/*')
        tuple val(sample_id_normal),path(bqsrbam_normal, stageAs: 'normal_snppileup/*')

output:
tuple val(sample_name), path("${sample_name}_snppileupout.gz"), emit: snppileup_out

script:
sample_name=sample_id_normal.split('_N')[0]

"""

snp-pileup --min-base-quality 20 --min-map-quality 15 --min-read-counts 25\,0 --pseudo-snps 100 --gzip /data1/daphni2/azenta_files/dbsnp_146.hg38.vcf.gz "${sample_name}_snppileupout.gz" ${bqsrbam_normal} ${bqsrbam_tumor}

"""

}
```

I get error as:

```
ERROR ~ Module compilation error
- file : /data1/users/nextflow_pipeline/scripts_pipeline/crusher_scripts/upgraded_split_csv/./snp_pileup.nf
- cause: Unexpected character: '"' @ line 23, column 3.
   """
     ^

1 error


 -- Check script 'main.nf' at line: 35 or see '.nextflow.log' file for more details
```

I don't understand what is causing the error.

Comment: I find nextflow's errors are often misleading. For me this usually indicates a syntax error within the script block. Though I don't see one there. 

Nextflow also doesn't like absolute paths. And it looks like you're supplying this one `/data1/daphni2/azenta_files/dbsnp_146.hg38.vcf.gz`. This may be the source of your error. So staging this file in the input declaration is my only suggestion.

Comment: @dthorbur Thank you. Can you please assist at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77304098/nextflow-data-not-being-published-to-output-dir-after-process-is-complete

Comment: I tried changing it. It still gives me same error of """ that is frustrating.

Comment: Hmm. This is confusing. Do you get the same error if you remove the entire `snp-pileup` command? There is a similar error when there is a syntax error in the process block. I tent to slowly remove things until it works as the error messages are very vague.